# Как узнать текущюю ориентацию на Айфоне?

Tags: ios, iphone

Привет !

Обыскал все, что мог, но найти подходящего ответа на свой вопрос так и не смог.

**Как узнать в какой ориентации пользователь запустил приложение?**

Мне это необходимо для того, применить соответствующий оринтации код.
Заметь те я знаю про функцию  `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` и использую ее, но в данном случаем мне нужно знать ориентацию именно НА МОМЕНТ ЗАПУСКА ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ.

Спасибо заранее за советы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

либо

```
//MyViewController - текущий view controller
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [MyViewController interfaceOrientation];
```

Список возвращаемых значений:

```
typedef enum {
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
} UIInterfaceOrientation;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, я обязательно отмечу Ваш ответ как правильный, только скажите, пожалуйста, а Вы проверяли этот метод на реальном устройстве ? Потому что у меня к сожалению пока такой возможности нету, а на эмуляторе он постоянно показывает 1 (что соответствует портрет моду) даже если я запускаю его в ландскейп моде "Project - Target - Summary - Supported Device Orientation only LANDSCAPE".

Comment: Нет, не проверял. Но у меня нет сомнений, что оно работает.

Comment: Ну тогда отлично !  Спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation
```

А вообще при запуске кажется дергается `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` у основного контроллера.

Comment: [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation не работает у меня для vieDidLoad.